# Append string after first iframe tag

Tags: regex, dom

i have number of iframe tags with string before and after them. i just want to add a string after first iframe tag.

Input:

```
aaaaa
<iframe src="anything"></iframe>
bbbb
<iframe src="anything"></iframe>
cccc
<iframe src="anything"></iframe>
```

Output:

```
aaaaa
<iframe src="anything"></iframe>
**String Added**
bbbb
<iframe src="anything"></iframe>
cccc
<iframe src="anything"></iframe>
```

thanks

Comment: do you want to do this with [tag:javascript], [tag:php], [tag:asp.net], [tag:perl],... ?

Comment: I answered, but I would recommend that you when you use Stack Overflow you always include what you have done first before asking your question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post a language, so I'll give you an answer in Javascript and you can adapt it to your language of choice.

Regex:
`(.*?<\/iframe>)(.*)`
Modifier:
`dot matches all`

Javascript:
`str = str.replace(/(.*?<\/iframe>)(.*)/m, '$1' + "** String Added **" + '$2');`

Tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/9LE2S/

```
var str = 'aaaaa\
<iframe src="anything"></iframe>\
bbbb\
<iframe src="anything"></iframe>\
cccc\
<iframe src="anything"></iframe>';

str = str.replace(/(.*?<\/iframe>)(.*)/m, '$1' + "** String Added **" + '$2');

alert(str);
```

Note that javascript isn't really the best for this because of the way it handles multi line strings, but if you get the element straight from the dom you probably won't run into that problem. This regex should be valid in any flavor though. Be sure to check what the modifier is for 'dot matches newline' - in this case, it was `m`, as you can see after the regex trailing slash.

Explanation:

`(` - Capture
`.*` - everything up to
`?`  - the first
`<\/iframe>` - instance of `<i/frame>`
`)` - end capture
`(` - capture
`.*` - everything else
`)`  - end capture

Then refer back to your capture groups and put something between them.

Answer (score 0):

in `var dom` or `$dom`:

```
aaaaa
<iframe src="anything"></iframe>
bbbb
<iframe src="anything"></iframe>
cccc
<iframe src="anything"></iframe>
```

**The replace function with javascript:**

```
var input = '\nString Added\n';    
dom.replace(/<\/iframe>[^\w](\w+)/ ,input + '$1');
```

**With php:**

```
$input = '\nString Added\n';    
preg_replace(/<\/iframe>[^\w](\w+)/ ,$input . '$1',$dom);
```

**Output:**

```
aaaaa
<iframe src="anything"></iframe>
String Added
bbbb
<iframe src="anything"></iframe>
cccc
<iframe src="anything"></iframe>
```

**What it does:**

- `<\/iframe>` = Search for the first closing Frame-Tag.
- `[^\w]` = Search forward until a word-character is found.
- `(\w+)` = capture the whole word and store it in $1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple JQuery solution:

`$('iframe').first().after('\n**String Added**\n');`